# if no querySelector is found (use replacement)

Tags: javascript

i have this code needed if no selector is found (to use replacement number 0)

```
const p = 20;
const p1 = document.querySelector("#").textContent;
const p2 = p1.replace(/[^\d:]/g, '');
const p4 = p1-(pt2);
document.getElementById("").value = p4;
```

example if I have p1 1 then this script should add 19 (if no number is found which is my problem) I would like to add something similar there `|| 0;` however, it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong here I've been looking for a new solution for a long time and didn't find it so I turn to the smarter ones

I would like to do something similar

```
const p1 = document.querySelector("#").textContent;
```

if this element is not found
replace in `|| 0;`

```
const p2 = p1.replace(/[^\d:]/g, '');
```

Comment: `#` is not a valid selector

Comment: you could do `const p1 = document.querySelector("#")?.textContent || 0;` that way if `document.querySelector("#")` returns `null` you won't throw an error

Comment: @Bravo thanx I'm just learning to know so well: D fortunately he solved this problem here thanks to the If method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const p1 = document.querySelector("#").textContent;
var p2;
if(p1.match(/[^\d:]/g)){
  p2 = p1.replace(/[^\d:]/g, '');
} else{
   p2 = 0
}
```

Comment: `need zero if they can't find the element (const p1 = document.querySelector("#").textContent;  
)  `   how to achieve it I tried your procedure here (unfortunately does not work)
(that query selector) if the script doesn't find it to put zero there

Comment: if this condition will be executed when you click on button then the condition should to be `if(document.querySelector("#id") === null) { var p2 = 0 } else {var p1 = document.querySelector("#id").textContent; var p2 = p1.replace(/[^\d:]/g, '') }` - but if this condition will be executed when you go to the page then wait for a while you can use `setInterval()` or `MutationObserver` - if your code will be executed directly when you open the page just use the condition above

Comment: Alsso are you sure that your regex is working i tested it and it's not replace anything i edited it to replace just the first number `^\d` or for first multiple numbers use `^\d+`

Answer (score 0):

use if else condition statement .

```
if(){

}else{

}
```